# Determine the number of terms needed to ensure an approximation of π to within $10^{-3}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, pi

I'm having troubles solving this problem:

> Using this:
>
> $$\frac{\pi}{4} = 4\arctan\left(\frac{1}{5}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{1}{239}\right)$$
>
> And The Maclaurin series for the arctangent function:
>
> $$\arctan(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{i+1}x^{2i-1}}{2i-1}$$
>
> Determine the number of terms that must be summed to ensure an approximation to $\pi$ to within $10^{-3}$.

I got this:
$$\frac{4}{2n+1} \left(\frac{4}{5^{2n+1}}-\frac{1}{239^{2n+1}}\right)<10^{-3}$$
However, I do not know what to do next.

Please help.

**EDIT:** I'm looking for an analytic approach.

Comment: It is sufficient to ask (and one does not lose much by doing so) that $$\frac{4}{2n+1}\frac{4}{5^{2n+1}}<10^{-3}$$ or, equivalently, $$(2n+1)5^{2n+1}>4\cdot4\cdot10^3=16\cdot8\cdot5^3=128\cdot5^3\approx125\cdot5^3=5^6$$ Thus, $n=3$ works. To finish this, check if $n=2$ works (it nearly does, but does not), and conclude.

Comment: @Did ok,so is it correct to say that if 

$$\frac{4}{2n+1}\frac{4}{5^{2n+1}}\ < 10^{-3}$$

then 

$$\frac{4}{2n+1} \left(\frac{4}{5^{2n+1}}-\frac{1}{239^{2n+1}}\right)<10^3$$

?

Comment: If you get rid of your persistent typo which makes you write $10^3$ instead of $10^{-3}$, then yes this is correct, *trivially*, since $a<c$ implies $a-b<c$ for every positive $b$...

Comment: @Did hahaha, freaking persisten typo. Thx a lot. Can I mark comments as "most helpful"?

Comment: @GustavoAlejandroCastellanos Did's answer is wrong btw. $n=2$ does work. This appears to have been propagated from the first post which numerically computed all of the errors incorrectly.

Comment: @adfriedman "Did's answer is wrong btw. n=2 does work" May I suggest that you try to become less hasty in decreeing that others' work is "wrong"? What I wrote is that $n=2$ fails the inequality $$\frac4{2n+1}\frac4{5^{2n+1}}<10^{-3}$$ written in my comment. Simply checking the subsequent exchanges with the OP would have made you realize this.

Comment: @Did The problem the OP is trying to answer called for "**the** number of terms that must be summed to ensure an approximation", not "**a** number of terms". If I asked what is **the** weight at which an elevator fails and you said a billion tons, then your answer would be wrong.

The OP should check the cases of $n=1$ and $n=2$, the latter of which it ambiguously appears you state doesn't work by stating "To finish this, check if $n=2$ works (it nearly does, but...)". In fact, they don't need to check if $n=2$ works for their own inequality, they should check it works for the actual series.

Comment: @adfriedman Yeah, and my comments are unambiguous in this respect.

Comment: @Did The OP asked where to go from there and you responded with "It is sufficient to ask..." Except it isn't sufficient, you have merely given the method to show how to show that the error is within $10^{-3}$ for $n=3$. You at no point mention that the cases of $n=1$ and $n=2$ need to be checked( **for the original series**), of which the latter is actually **the** number of terms that must be summed to ensure the required error bound. So you haven't told to OP where to go from there at all and hence haven't answered the question, or at most, you answered incompletely.

Comment: @adfriedman Sorry to disappoint your appetite for controversy but, since I stand by the content of my first comment to you (still here for everybody to see) and since I see nothing constructive in your subsequent interventions, I plan to skip to more fruitful activities than answering your next installments (if any).

Answer (score 1):

In an alternating decreasing series, the error is smaller than the first term dropped. You can evaluate the two arc tangent series by equally sharing out the error.

Then

$$\begin{align}\frac45&=0.8\\
\frac4{3\cdot5^3}&=0.0106667\cdots\\
\frac4{5\cdot5^5}&=0.000256\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\frac1{239}=0.00418410041841\cdots.\\
\end{align}$$

Clearly the next term is well below $0.0005$, and we can do with

$$\frac45-\frac4{375}-\frac1{239}=0.7851\cdots$$

to be compared to the true value $0.78539816\cdots$.

**Update**: I used a tolerance $10^{-3}$ on $\frac\pi4$ instead of on $\pi$, so the discussion must be rewritten with $0.00025$. By luck, the given estimate is still valid, as explained below.

---

From the above, we can even conclude that the error is smaller than $0.000256$. But for this to hold, we need to keep an extra digit and write $0.78515\cdots$ (true error $0.000249$).

One might argue that $0.000256>0.00025$ and there is a risk of the estimate being wrong, but we remain on the safe side because the error on the second series is certainly much smaller than $0.00025$ and an imbalanced sharing can be used.

---

For a fully analytical solution, you can express the truncation criterion of the series for $p\arctan(1/q)$ as

$$\frac p{(2n-1)q^{2n-1}}<\epsilon.$$

This is satisfied (a little pessimistically for small $n$) with

$$n=\left\lceil\frac{\log_q\frac p\epsilon+1}2\right\rceil.$$

This estimate tells us to truncate from the fourth and second terms onward, respectively.

Comment: The alternating truncation error is on the next term, not the current, so I think you mean
$$ \frac{p}{(2n+1)q^{2n+1}} < \epsilon$$

Also, if you want to "split the error evenly" then you need this less than $\epsilon/2$, which I believe gives the criteria

$$n=\left\lceil \frac{\log_q \tfrac{2p}{5\epsilon} - 1}{2} \right\rceil$$

(though there might be slight algebra mistakes in that. I'm tired and kind of bored of this question.)

Comment: @adfriedman: no on your two remarks. The inequality is established for the first term to be neglected, and terms are numbered from $n=1$. It gives $n=4$ and $n=2$ respectively. And the $\epsilon$ is not the total $\epsilon$ but the one that you use for a single series. In this case, $0.0005$.

Comment: That is a very non-standard presentation, at least in comparison to the AP and US calc 2 approach, which is normally given by $|s-s_n|\leq|a_{n+1}|$ as the approximate error estimates. If the OP is asking for the last term before truncation, then why phrase it as the first term included in truncation?

And I would know to use $\epsilon=0.0005$, but that is not at all obvious from your answer.

Comment: @adfriedman: my text leaves no ambiguity about the conventions. The $\epsilon$ is explicitly said to be for a single series.

Comment: I said non-standard and confusing, not ambiguous. You should complete the "fully analytical solution" section, as I doubt many others will be able to make the jumps between steps, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First we must establish that we are actually dealing with a proper alternating series so that the alternating series error remainder estimate may be used. This may be done trivially by:
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{4} &= 4\arctan \tfrac{1}{5} - \arctan \tfrac{1}{239}\\
&= 4 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{i+1} (1/5)^{2i-1}}{2i-1} - \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i+1} (1/239)^{2i-1}}{2i-1}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{2i-1} \underbrace{\left[ 4\left(\tfrac{1}{5}\right)^{2i-1} - \left(\tfrac{1}{239}\right)^{2i-1}\right]}_{> 0}
\end{align}
Hence this is an alternating series, with terms that decrease monotonically in $i$ (in an absolute sense). So,

\begin{align}
\left|\pi - 4\sum_{i=1}^{n} (-1)^{i+1} \frac{ 4\left(\tfrac{1}{5}\right)^{2i-1} - \left(\tfrac{1}{239}\right)^{2i-1}}{2i-1}\right|
&\leq 4\frac{4\left(\tfrac{1}{5}\right)^{2n+1}-\left(\tfrac{1}{239}\right)^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\
&\leq \frac{16}{(2n+1) 5^{2n+1}}
\leq \frac{16}{5^{2n+2}} = 0.64\cdot\frac{1}{5^{2n}}
\end{align}
So $n\geq 3$ suffices. Obviously $n=1$ fails, but for $n=2$ we obtain

$$\pi - \frac{ 5359397032}{1706489875} \approx 0.000995624 < 10^{-3}$$

So at $2$ terms or more are sufficient.